# VBA does not active

Tags: excel, vba

I suggest that my workbook contains a VBA code below. But It does not run when I opened my workbook too.

```
Sub Appl_StatusBar() 
      Application.StatusBar = "SupportABC" 
End Sub
```

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44

Comment: https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/

Comment: Google your question first.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your code in the Workbook Open Event it will do what you need. To do this click the top dropdown where it says "(General)" and hit "Workbook". In the right dropdown select "Open" and save your code there". See below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.StatusBar = "SupportABC"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the worst (almost) correct answer that I have ever seen. Read this and update your answer to tell what exactly OP needs to do. https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/